# Ranking alternatives depending on their score with their names

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I want to rank some alternatives depending on their score and to print the name of each alternative with its ranking, how can I do this ?

Here is MWE :

```
import java.util.Arrays;
public class Ranking {
public static void main(String[] args) {

//The score of the alternatives :
double [] score = new double [4] ;
score[0] = 6.75 ;
score[1] = 9.0 ;
score[2] = 6.75 ;
score[3] = 5.50;

//The name of the alternatives :
String [] name = new String [4] ;
name[0] = "a1";
name[1] = "a2";
name[2] = "a3";
name[3] = "a4";

//Descending Sorting the score array like this :
for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
score[i]= - score[i];

Arrays.sort(score);

for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
score[i]= - score[i];

//print the result
for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
System.out.println(score[i] + " rank = " + (i+1));
}
//result :
//9.0 rank = 1
//6.75 rank = 2
//6.75 rank = 3
//5.5 rank = 4
```

But I want this kind of result :

```
name : a2 a1 a3 a4
rank : 1  2  3  4
```

How can I do this ?

Comment: You make it hard to help you because the program is barely readable without indentation.

Comment: I suggest you take a step back from the Java code. Try to describe **in words** the steps you need to solve the problem. Once you can clearly explain these steps to another person, then try to translate them into code.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `Map<String, Double>` for this.

Try below example:

```
Map<String, Double> map = new HashMap<>();
      map.put("a1", 6.75);
      map.put("a2", 9.0);
      map.put("a3", 6.8);

      map = map.entrySet().stream()
      .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue(Comparator.reverseOrder()))
      .collect(Collectors.toMap(
         Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, (e1, e2) -> e1, LinkedHashMap::new));

//Iterate through the map
```

You will get the answer in reverse sorted order.

`.sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue(Comparator.reverseOrder()))` is used to sort by values and `LinkedHashMap::new` is used to maintain ordering of `Map`

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted, I never worked with Map before, it's a good start, thank you !

Comment: @RedOne welcome. You can accept the answer if it solves your problem.

Comment: i have one last question, how can I print the result ?

Comment: @RedOne If you just want to see the values you can use `System.out.println(map);`. To process each value you need to iterate through the `map`. You can google it or see https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/iterate-map-java/

Answer (score 1):

You sort individual array so the result cannot be mapped between name - rank.

In java, the normal way is to abstract your data to object and operate on them:

Declare your model class:

```
public YourModel {
  private String name;
  private double score;

  public Rank(String name, double score) {
    this.name = name;
    this.score = score;
  }
  // you create your getters/ setters
}
```

Add data to your array:

```
YourModel[] models = new YourModel[4];
models[0] = new YourModel("a1", 6.75D);
```

... add other models ...

Sort your arrays:

```
Arrays.sort(models, Comparator.comparing(YourModel::getScore));
```

After this step, you will have your array sorted:

```
[{"a2", 9.0} ....]
```

And you can print your result:

```
for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
   System.out.println(models[i].getName() + " rank = " + (i+1));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this, I try to run it but I get an erreor "incompatible type void cannot be converted to YourModel[][]" on the sortedModels line, how can I fix this ?

Comment: Ok now it works, but I get the Ascending sorting, how can I get the reverse Order ?

Comment: Add `.reversed()` to comparator: `Comparator.comparing(YourModel::getScore).reversed()`

Comment: Cheer! glad it helps

Answer (score 1):

When you have to sort something, you should look at `TreeSet` or `TreeMap` structures. Actually `Array` is not where sorting is primary function.

It seems that you have unique `names` for all objects, then you have to use `TreeSet` with reverce comparator. As result when you iterate over the `Set`, you get required order:

```
final class Model {

    private final String name;
    private final double score;

    public Model(String name, double score) {
        this.name = name;
        this.score = score;
    }
}

final Comparator<Model> reverceScore = (d1, d2) -> {
    if (d1.name.equalsIgnoreCase(d2.name))
        return 0;

    int res = Double.compare(d2.score, d1.score);
    return res != 0 ? res : d1.name.compareTo(d2.name);
};

Set<Model> data = new TreeSet<>(reverceScore);
data.add(new Model("a1", 6.75));
data.add(new Model("a2", 9));
data.add(new Model("a3", 6.75));
data.add(new Model("a4", 5.5));

int rank = 1;

for(Model model : data)
    System.out.println("rank: " + rank++ + " - name: " + model.name + ", score: " + model.score);
```